# regex to only match a full set of two-part pattern (kinda non-greedy)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I use `preg_match_all` to get all matches of a two-part pattern as:

```
/<(.*?)>[:|\s]+{(.*?)}/
```

In a string like:

```
<First>: something <second>: {Second} something <Third>: {Third}
```

I want to match:

```
<second>: {Second}
```

instead of:

```
<First>: something <second>: {Second}
```

[Working Example](https://regexr.com/4jjg9)

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Use `<([^<>]*)>[:\s]+{(.*?)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use limited repeated set instead of lazy repetition inside the brackets:

```
<([^>]*)>[:\s]+{(.*?)}
```

The change is to replace `<(.*?)>` with `<([^>]*)>`. The initial version matches the first `<` then takes lazily any character until it finds `:{Second}`. If you restrict repetition, regex engine will try to start with `<First>`, but when it doesn't find `:{...}` after that, it'll try with the next `<`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S1auX3/1)